# Translating using Translation Workbench in a Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, postinstall, package-install, translation-workbench, standardlayout

I'm using translation workbench in my managed package to support different languages. I've so far had the necessity to translate just a couple of field labels in standard User page layouts.

These works fine. As in when the user installs the package and just changes the user's language, the labels gets translated.

Now, I have added one more section header into the translation and a new package is created, but for some reason, the section header is not getting translated by default. I've to activate the languages in the translation workbench manually for it to translate the section header to user's language.

Is this how it works by default? Or am I missing something? Or can we achieve this in post install script?

Thanks in advance! Peace!